# change variables using str_replace on eval

Tags: php, eval, str-replace

i want to know how to change variables on eval

Look the code, please help me

```
$status = "HD";

$vari = "XX";

$condition = "if($status<>'99' && $status<>'XX' && $status<>'XM' && $status<> 'XD' && $status<> 'XY' && $status<> 'XE') 
{ echo 'YES'; } else { echo 'NO'; }";

$condition = eval($condition );

echo $condition;
echo "<hr>";

$resp = str_replace('status','vari',$condition);
echo eval($resp);
```

The problem is, not change the variables.. see if changes results YES or NO...

And i want to using this work on my WHILE Expression

```
while($condition) {

   ...

}
```

Thank You

Comment: If you have to use `eval` then you are in some serious trouble

Comment: Please don't TYPE YOUR QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS. It's hard to read, it won't get you help any sooner, and it's annoying. (It's also considered SHOUTING, which is rude.) Thanks.

Comment: Your second "$condition =" changes the value of condition. Since your statement doesn't return anything, $condition will be null. So, $resp is a str_replace on null. That is still null.

Comment: The real question is - why you must use eval and don't put your code directly inside the loop or whatever!?

Comment: See the [man page on `eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and notice that `eval($str)` does not return the same string it received as an argument. As @kainaw observes, you have overwritten it with what it returns before your second `str_replace()` attempt.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i tried to go in the PHP page but I could not hit it, am new to this website and I need help. Please help me. Sorry for the caps

Comment: @Philipp I'm not putting the code directly on while, because I'm dynamically generating the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if i wrong, but from your code above, when you eval you $condition string, you put it back again into $condition. Unless your evaluated code have "return" in it, it will return null ( reff : http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

But your problem is actually miss-use of " on $condition. When you use " to wrap string(s) on php, it will change every variable on that string to the value defined for that variable above that code.

So, instead having your code evaluate by php, you're actually sending wrong code to eval().

your current $condition code is :

```
if(HD<>'99' && HD<>'XX' && HD<>'XM' && HD<> 'XD' && HD<> 'XY' && HD<> 'XE') { echo 'YES'; } else { echo 'NO'; }
```

and what you're trying to achive is :

```
if($status<>"99" && $status<>"XX" && $status<>"XM" && $status<> "XD" && $status<> "XY" && $status<> "XE") { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; }
```

Please change " to ' since string(s) wrap in ' will be as it is (if you want to put ' inside it, please escaped it using backslash (\) ) and see what happen.

my work around :

```
$status = "HD";
$vari = "XX";
$condition = 'if($status<>"99" && $status<>"XX" && $status<>"XM" && $status<> "XD" && $status<> "XY" && $status<> "XE") { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; }';
eval($condition );
echo $condition;
echo "<hr>";
$resp = str_replace('status','vari',$condition);
eval($resp);
```

Comment: @Mock. Rasyd,  Thank you, your two results were great

Comment: anytime, but what is "my two results" ?? anyway, please look another way before using eval like the other(s) comment(s) above. I'd rather generate a new php file using "while.." and then redirect user to execute that php file.

Comment: can i use as result an $variable = 'yes' or false $variable = 'no' instead echo 'yes' echo 'no' ?

Comment: you can use "$result = eval($condition)" and inside $condition, you can replace "Echo" with "return". And then, below "$result = eval($condition)", you can try to echo it to find whether the result is being passed correctly.